# Composer plugin: узнать директорию проекта

Tags: php, composer

Пишу дурацкий скрипт для композера. Требуется узнать папку проекта, чтобы скидывать при инсталляции некоторые файлы в %папка-проекта%/tmp (в проекте есть файлы, которые из-за не очень правильной организации репы теряются при инсталляции). Битый час уже изучаю сорцы, но нигде не вижу ссылки на корень проекта. Как получить этот путь, безопасно ли использовать `getcwd()` для его определения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При получении ключа -d (работы в директории, отличной от текущей) Composer выполняет команду `chdir()`, поэтому использование `getcwd()` должно быть вполне безопасным. Остается последний вариант - использование Composer прямо из скрипта PHP - но этот сценарий маловероятен, и, к тому же, скорее всего Composer все равно будет опираться на текущую папку и выполнять `chdir`, если в полученный им конфигурации стоит отличная от текущей директория.